# Get higher value id of list in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-lists

I have a list:

```
<ul id="testList">
  <li id="3"></li>
  <li id="2"></li>
  <li id="1"></li>
</ul>
```

I need get to higher value id of li element with jQuery. In this example it would be, 3. Then append class "last". I tried with each function but don't work.

```
$('#testList li').each(function(index, li){

    //Here obtain a higher value id                         
    $('#testList li').last().addClass('last');                  

});
```

I hope someone can help me. Thank you very much!
Regards!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Math.max` and `map()` to get maximum id value and then `addClass()`

```js
var h = Math.max.apply(null, $('#testList li').map(function() {
  return $(this).attr('id');
}))

$('#' + h).addClass('last');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="testList">
  <li id="3"></li>
  <li id="2"></li>
  <li id="1"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Nice.  Knew there was a better way, completely forgot about `map`.

Comment: Thank you guys you're awesome! I solve my problem! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the most efficient way, but this would do it:

```
// initialize the max value to a low number
var max = 0;
// iterate over each li item in the list
$('#testList li').each(function() {
    // ensure we have a number
    var id = parseInt($(this).prop('id'));
    if (! isNaN(id)) {
        max = Math.max(max, id);
    }
});

// Given that max contains an ID, just pass that in to the selector to add class
$('#' + max).addClass('last');
```